# implement close button in angular directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make an alert message and the layout looks like this

```
<div class="alert">
    <p>Some alert content!</p>
</div>
```

So far so good, now I want to make a directive to add a close button to this alert and I want to hide the alert when i press the button.

I created this directive

```
myApp.directive('alert', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.prepend('<a class="alert-close" ng-click="close()"></a>');
        }
    }
});
```

Now this directive adds the close button, but I don't know how to implement this button to hide the alert which is inside.

I hope this can be done, thank you in advance for any tips on how to do this.

Comment: why not include the `div.alert` as well in the template for directive, and use `ng-show` on div.alert to flipped on `ng-click` of your `<a>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a controller to your directive as well where you can add the close method to the scope.

```
myApp.directive('alert', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'C',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            elem.prepend('<a class="alert-close" ng-click="close(this)"></a>');
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
          $scope.close = function (obj) {
            // manipulate obj (the anchor link) or traverse up the dom etc.
          };
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thank you very much , i used this and a combination of transclude and a template and it seems everything looks ok :)